# partial searching of an attribute value using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to search for a partial value of the attribute and *not the whole* of a specific node.
I do not know how to do it. You are appreciated in advance for your kind help.
E.g:
I want to search for all "book"s in this XML document in which the attribute value of "isbn" is started with "00-05" disregarding the rest:

```
<book isbn="00-05-100-00"></book>

<book isbn="00-05-120-35"></book>

<book isbn="00-16-456-01"></book>
```

Answer (score 11):

There is [starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) function in XPath that you can use:

```
//book[starts-with(@isbn, '00-05')]
```